# Jetpack Compose expanding BottomSheet of BottomSheetScaffold only works after recomposition

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to have a way to show a BottomSheet from everywhere within my app, for that I use the `BottomSheetScaffold` and a LiveData object that holds the current composable function which is observed as state:

```kotlin
val sheetContent by MusicHub.state.bottomSheet.getContent().observeAsState()

BottomSheetScaffold(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
    scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
    sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
    sheetContent = sheetContent!!
)
```

I use the BottomSheet as a context menu in my app. For example when i longClick on a playlist in my app it sets the content of the BottomSheet and shows it like this:

```kotlin
PlaylistItem(
    // ...
    onLongClick = {
        // Set the LiveData composable
        MusicHub.state.bottomSheet.setContent {
            PlaylistContextMenuTest(playlist!!, viewModel)
        }
        
        // Expand BottomSheet
        scope.launch {
            MusicHub.state.bottomSheet.expand()
        }
    }
)
```

In general this works but the first time the BottomSheet gets expanded it shows for a split second before it disappears at the bottom again. Here is a small GIF:

[image]

My guess is that somehow the size of the BottomSheet is not recalculated yet and hence it only works in the next recomposition. Coming from web dev i would say its a typical case of requestAnimationFrame but i  don't quite know how to solve this issue in compose.

Edit:

PlaylistContextMenuTest code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun PlaylistContextMenuTest(playlist: Playlist, viewModel: LibraryViewModel = activityViewModel()){
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .navigationBarsPadding()
            // TODO: Replace that with a percentage of the screen height
            .heightIn(max = 384.dp)
            .verticalScroll(scrollState),
        content = {
            ContextMenu {
                repeat(4){
                    addOption(R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp, "Delete"){
                        Timber.d("Delete Playlist")
                        viewModel.deletePlaylist(playlist)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Full ContextMenu source: (https://pastebin.com/sg4ed96L)

Comment: can u post the code for `PlaylistContextMenuTest(playlist!!, viewModel)` composable

Comment: @SantanuSur sure, just updated the post.

Comment: Having the same issue, where I have to click twice whenever the BottomSheet's content height is changed.

Comment: @pentexnyx Did you find a solution for your problem yet?

Comment: @Nimmi not for ModalBottomSheetLayout unfortunately :/
Does the answer I posted help a bit?

Comment: How do you dim background what do u use? On my side back ground is not dimming :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved with a new release of jetpack compose. I am not sure if it was beta 8 or 9 but everything works as intended now.

Comment: Beta 9. So happy about that <3

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be right. The first time it seems to be re-calculating the BottomSheet's height.

As this does not change on the second try, it will then be displayed.

Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67435416/10905230) help you?

It seems to work out quite okay for BottomSheetScaffold, but not for ModalBottomSheetLayout (the thing I was looking for as you can see in the comments of the linked answer).

Edit: [Accompanist's Navigation Material](https://google.github.io/accompanist/navigation-material/#bottom-sheet-destinations) is also worth a look.

Comment: The Accompanist sample is for Modal bottomsheet, not Scaffold bottomsheet.