# How to apply bottom sheet for multiple text in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-bottomsheetdialog

I am try to learning jetpack compose those days, so I want to learning bottom sheet in jetpack compose, I do it just for one text, but I want to use it for multiple text, I have one example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68861903/10991969), but I am not sure how to implement to my project, is there any solution for more than two text button to apply bottom sheet?

```
@Composable
fun BottomSheetMyScreen() {
    val modalBottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(initialValue = 
  ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetContent = {
            BottomSheetFirstScreen()
         

        },
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 5.dp, topEnd = 5.dp),
        sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Red,
       
    ) {
        Scaffold(

            backgroundColor = Color.Red
        ) {
            MyScreen(
                scope = scope, state = modalBottomSheetState

            )}}}
 
@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    scope: CoroutineScope, state: ModalBottomSheetState,

) {

            MainRow(
                name = "name1",
                onClick = {  scope.launch {
                    state.show()
                }}
            )

            MainRow(
                name = "name2",
                onClick = { scope.launch {
                    state.show()
                } }

            )}}
     
@Composable
fun MainRow(
    name: String,
    onClick: () -> Unit

    ) {

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp)
            .clickable(onClick = onClick),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(150.dp)

           ) {

            Text(
                text = name,
               
            )}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit Your Code, you can use this code:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun BottomSheetMyScreen() {
    val modalBottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        initialValue =
        ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden
    )
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val sheetContentState = remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetContent = {
            when (sheetContentState.value) {
                0 -> {
                    BottomSheetFirstScreen()
                }
                1 -> {
                    BottomSheetSecondScreen()
                }
            }
        },
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 5.dp, topEnd = 5.dp),
        sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Red,
    ) {
        Scaffold(
            backgroundColor = Color.Red
        ) {
            MyScreen(
                scope = scope, state = modalBottomSheetState, sheetContentState = sheetContentState
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Main Row

```
@Composable
fun MainRow(
    name: String,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Text(
            text = name,
            modifier = Modifier.clickable { onClick.invoke() }
        )
    }
}
```

And MyScreen

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    scope: CoroutineScope,
    state: ModalBottomSheetState,
    sheetContentState: MutableState<Int>
) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        MainRow(
            name = "name 1",
            onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    sheetContentState.value = 0
                    state.show()
                }
            }
        )
        MainRow(
            name = "name 2",
            onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    sheetContentState.value = 1
                    state.show()
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx for ur answer, but can u pls answer according to question, is it possible to apply for question

Comment: Yes, i wrote an answer an example for you, just implement in your project as you want. If you want to handle click listener of two button, just write your code inside text1ButtonOnClick and text2ButtonOnClick method

Comment: I am not get it ur answer, sorry

Comment: You want your bottom sheet to have 2 TextButton, isn't that right?

Comment: no I have two button and I want to use botton sheet for those bottons ,  both button located on row, I have to apply for 2 or more button that bottom sheet

Comment: Do you want to show the bottom sheet with these buttons?

Comment: yes sure I want to use it for two text

Comment: If you see my answer, i wrote it for you, just in onClick of your button change the state of your bottom sheet, scope.launch {
                sheetState.bottomSheetState.expand()
            }

Comment: as I said I am not understand ur answer, it is not related to my question

Comment: Ok, i use your code, and edit for you

Comment: I edit My Answer and use your code, just I edit and it's what you want

Comment: tnx so much for ur answer, but I have two row and every row have one text, when I click the any  text I want to open bottom sheet, but every text have own screen view

Comment: Ok I update it again

Comment: I update my answer, please check if that is what you want, I hope it can help you

Comment: my big problem here,  sheetContent = {
            BottomSheetFirstScreen()
        }, I will add second screen to here also?

Comment: when I click the name1 one screen will open, but when I click name2 it will open other  bottom sheet screen

Comment: You mean, you want different screen per click on text for bottomsheet?

Comment: yes definitely,  I want like that

Comment: ok so you want your bottom sheet content change per click, ok I wrote it for you

Comment: I update my answer again, I think it is what you want

Comment: I understand now, tnx so so much, ur help appreciated. :))

Comment: I am glad to be helpful :)

Comment: tnx so so much :)